# How can I rename a Symfony project?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, installation, rename

I wrote this line into my terminal and accidently pressed enter

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project
```

Now a project called "my-project" was created, which is not the name of my project. The name is "Sun". But what can I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rename your directory created "my-project" to "Sun" or you can delete it and launch this command:

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton Sun
```

In this case a project named Sun will be created

Comment: How can I delete it?

Comment: Delete the directory for example @Jarla

Comment: ah ok, now I understand! Thank you very much!